# Declaring an empty array of type Edge Graphx

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm reading data from file to create edges of graph. I've declare an array and adding edges in it one by one. This code is working fine:

```
class AIRecipes() 
case class edgeProperty(val relation: String, val usedIn: String) extends AIRecipes

var edgeArray = Array(Edge(0L, 0L, edgeProperty("", "")))
edgeArray = edgeArray ++ Array(Edge(VertexId, VertexId, edgeProperty("", "")) )
```

But in first line, instead of declaring an extra edge with dummy values, I want to declare an empty array like that:

```
var edgeArray = Array.empty[Edge[(Long, Long, Object)]]
edgeArray = edgeArray ++ Array(Edge(VertexId, VertexId, edgeProperty("", "")) )
```

But it give me following compilation error on '++':

> type mismatch;  found   : Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[_ >:
>   (Long, Long, Object) with
>   net.sansa_stack.template.spark.rdf.TripleReader.edgeProperty <:
>   Product with Serializable]]  required:
>   Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[(Long, Long, Object)]] Note:
>   org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[_ >: (Long, Long, Object) with
>   net.sansa_stack.template.spark.rdf.TripleReader.edgeProperty <:
>   Product with Serializable] >: org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[(Long,
>   Long, Object)], but class Array is invariant in type T. You may wish
>   to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >:
>   org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[(Long, Long, Object)]`.

I also tried this:

```
edgeArray :+ Array(Edge(VertexId, VertexId, edgeProperty("", "")) )
```

It don't give me compilation error but nothing is being added in array.

Comment: Could you post signature of `edgeProperty`?

Comment: @user9613318 edgeProperty is a class. `class AIRecipes(),                         
case class edgeProperty(val relation: String, val usedIn: String) extends AIRecipes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of the first array is incorrect. Note that `Edge` is parameterized only by its property so the type of the expression you are trying to merge is `Array[Edge[edgeProperty]]`:

```
scala> :t Array(Edge(0L, 0L, edgeProperty("", "")))
Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[edgeProperty]]
```

while you define variable as `Array.empty[Edge[(Long, Long, Object)]]`.

The `Object` part is the second problem. As you can read in the exception message, `Array` (as any other mutable container) is invariant. So if you really want to go with `Object` you'll have to:

```
scala> var edgeArray = Array.empty[Edge[Object]]
edgeArray: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Object]] = Array()

scala> edgeArray = edgeArray ++ (Array(Edge(1L, 2L, edgeProperty("", "")) ): Array[Edge[Object]])
edgeArray: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Object]] = [Lorg.apache.spark.graphx.Edge;@338
```

but I still recommend

```
scala> var edgeArray = Array.empty[Edge[edgeProperty]]
edgeArray: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[edgeProperty]] = Array()

scala> edgeArray = edgeArray ++ Array(Edge(1L, 2L, edgeProperty("", "")) )
edgeArray: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[edgeProperty]] = [Lorg.apache.spark.graphx.Edge;@7d59e8d4
```

Comment: I changed `var edgeArray = Array.empty[Edge[(Long, Long, Object)]]` to `var edgeArray = Array.empty[Edge[edgeProperty]]` and it is working fine now. Thanks :)